# Not able to call touch event in iphone when clicking on a button

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, uitouch

i need to call touch event in iphone when i clicked on a button.
 i have the following code which is not calling touch event

Please any one let me know how to resolve this.

The button code is as follows.

-(void)method
{

BottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];

btnRefresh =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnRefresh setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRefresh setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnRefresh setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ggrey1.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btnRefresh setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ggrey1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [btnRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(KeyboardRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnRefresh setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [btnRefresh setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

```
[BottomView addSubview:btnRefresh];
```

if (self.isPortrait) {

```
    [btnRefresh setFrame:CGRectMake(71, 0, 40, 6)];

    [BottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, 320, 41)];
}
else{

    [btnRefresh setFrame:CGRectMake(94, 0, 61, 8)];

    [BottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 123, 480, 41)];
}
```

}

the above methos is calling and the

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{
NSLog(@"yes");
}

is not calling when i click on refresh butotn.

can any one help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the @selector for touchesBegan. You instead have it for KeyboardRefresh. Don't check for button pressage in touchesBegan. Instead replaces your touchesBegan with:

```
-(void)KeyboardRefresh:(id) sender
{ 
    NSLog(@"yes");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the message. but i need to call both and also i need to call touches moved and touches end is there any idea. it has to show another button when click on refresh button.

Comment: I'm not sure but, if your worried about buttons you probably just want to make multiple methods for the different states. i.e UIControlEventTouchUpInside